# How to keep text column on the right stay on the right

Tags: html, css

What's the simplest way to keep the text on the right in that column? I'm floating my image of the peach on the left, but when the text on the right goes beyond the image of the peach the positioning of it goes below the peach.

How do I keep the positioning of the text on the right and not have it go into the left column?

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/7esyct27/

```
<div class="alignleft">
    <p>
        <img alt="Peach" src="http://www.frankfarms.com/images/Peach.png" />
    </p>
    <p><strong>Peach</strong>
        <br />Calories 59
        <br>Total Fat 0.4 g
        <br>Sodium 0 mg</p>
</div>
<p>The peach (Prunus persica) is a deciduous tree, native to Northwest China, in the region between the Tarim Basin and the north slopes of the Kunlun Shan mountains, where it was first domesticated and cultivated.[2] It bears an edible juicy fruit also called a peach. The species name persica refers to its widespread cultivation in Persia, whence it was transplanted to Europe. It belongs to the genus Prunus which includes the cherry and plum, in the family Rosaceae. The peach is classified with the almond in the subgenus Amygdalus, distinguished from the other subgenera by the corrugated seed shell.</p>
<p>Peaches and nectarines are the same species, even though they are regarded commercially as different fruits. In contrast to peaches, whose fruits present the characteristic fuzz on the skin, nectarines are characterized by the absence of fruit-skin trichomes (fuzz-less fruit); genetic studies suggest nectarines are produced due to a recessive allele, whereas peaches are produced from a dominant allele for fuzzy skin. China is the world's largest producer of peaches</p>
<p>Prunus persica grows to 4–10 m (13–33 ft) tall and 6 in. in diameter. The leaves are lanceolate, 7–16 cm (2.8–6.3 in) long, 2–3 cm (0.79–1.18 in) broad, pinnately veined. The flowers are produced in early spring before the leaves; they are solitary or paired, 2.5–3 cm diameter, pink, with five petals. The fruit has yellow or whitish flesh, a delicate aroma, and a skin that is either velvety (peaches) or smooth (nectarines) in different cultivars. The flesh is very delicate and easily bruised in some cultivars, but is fairly firm in some commercial varieties, especially when green. The single, large seed is red-brown, oval shaped, approximately 1.3–2 cm long, and is surrounded by a wood-like husk. Peaches, along with cherries, plums and apricots, are stone fruits (drupes). There are various heirloom varieties, including the Indian peach, which arrives in the latter part of the summer.</p>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.alignleft {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 30px 20px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve what you are looking for is to just wrap your paragraphs in a div and add a class that floats it to the left as well and then add a width to it. This will allow it to stay just to the right of the peach and when the screen gets smaller it will push it down below the peach object.

```
.alignleft {
float: left;
margin: 0px 30px 20px 0;
}

.alignright {
float: left;
width: 75%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/YoshiMaster/7esyct27/1/

Just wrap the text in a div and float it right, give it a percentage width. I chose 20% for the left div and 79% for the right div.

I also took out the margins.

```
.alignleft {
    float: left;

    width:20%
}
#right {float:right; width:78%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the text you want in the right column in another 'div' and give it property of table in display:

```
.alignright {
    display:table;
}
```

And here's the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alonbrimzy/7esyct27/4/

Answer (score 0):

With javascript   you can do this: [look at the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pauldic/ew46hupa/)

```
.alignleft {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 30px 20px 0;
}
.nextDiv{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all your `p` inside a `div` and apply this `CSS`

```
<div class="alignleft">
    <p>
        <img alt="Peach" src="http://www.frankfarms.com/images/Peach.png" />
    </p>
    <p><strong>Peach</strong>
        <br />Calories 59
        <br>Total Fat 0.4 g
        <br>Sodium 0 mg</p>
</div>
<div><p>The peach (Prunus persica) is a deciduous tree, native to Northwest China, in the region between the Tarim Basin and the north slopes of the Kunlun Shan mountains, where it was first domesticated and cultivated.[2] It bears an edible juicy fruit also called a peach. The species name persica refers to its widespread cultivation in Persia, whence it was transplanted to Europe. It belongs to the genus Prunus which includes the cherry and plum, in the family Rosaceae. The peach is classified with the almond in the subgenus Amygdalus, distinguished from the other subgenera by the corrugated seed shell.</p>
<p>Peaches and nectarines are the same species, even though they are regarded commercially as different fruits. In contrast to peaches, whose fruits present the characteristic fuzz on the skin, nectarines are characterized by the absence of fruit-skin trichomes (fuzz-less fruit); genetic studies suggest nectarines are produced due to a recessive allele, whereas peaches are produced from a dominant allele for fuzzy skin. China is the world's largest producer of peaches</p>
<p>Prunus persica grows to 4–10 m (13–33 ft) tall and 6 in. in diameter. The leaves are lanceolate, 7–16 cm (2.8–6.3 in) long, 2–3 cm (0.79–1.18 in) broad, pinnately veined. The flowers are produced in early spring before the leaves; they are solitary or paired, 2.5–3 cm diameter, pink, with five petals. The fruit has yellow or whitish flesh, a delicate aroma, and a skin that is either velvety (peaches) or smooth (nectarines) in different cultivars. The flesh is very delicate and easily bruised in some cultivars, but is fairly firm in some commercial varieties, especially when green. The single, large seed is red-brown, oval shaped, approximately 1.3–2 cm long, and is surrounded by a wood-like husk. Peaches, along with cherries, plums and apricots, are stone fruits (drupes). There are various heirloom varieties, including the Indian peach, which arrives in the latter part of the summer.</p></div>

.alignleft {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 30px 20px 0;
    width:20%;
}
div{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:70%;
}
```